# How can i acces shell environment variables in a Perl script

Tags: oracle, perl, perlscript

### What i have

I have a Perl script that check connection to oracle database .Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
my $ORACLE_SID =  $ENV{'ORACLE_SID'};
$\="\n";
print "exported variable=$ORACLE_SID";
print "Connecting to DB..";
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:host=oracle;sid=$ORACLE_SID;port=1521', 'books_admin/MyPassword', '',{ RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0 })or die print ("could not connect! $DBI::errstr \n");
```

I have exported ORACLE_SID by `export ORACLE_SID=ORCLCDB` 
The output of this code is

```
    exported variable=ORCLCDB
    Connecting to DB..
    DBI connect('host=oracle;sid=$ORACLE_SID;port=1521','books_admin/MyPassword',...) failed: ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor (DBD ERROR: OCIServerAttach) at perl.pl line 8.
```

Seems like ORACLE_SID is picked up by Perl but it is not used in sid=$ORACLE_SID.
Why print function can use $ORACLE_SID and sid=$ORACLE_SID can't fetch the value

Comment: @Dada No luck .still the value not coming to sid=''This part'

Comment: @xaglez You should show what changes you made to your code after reading that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> print "exported variable=$ORACLE_SID";
> ```

This works because you have a double-quoted string. And variables are expanded in doubled-quoted strings.

> ```
> my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:host=oracle;sid=$ORACLE_SID;port=1521', 'books_admin/MyPassword', '',{ RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0 })or die print ("could not connect! $DBI::errstr \n");
> ```

Here, your `$ORACLE_SID` is inside a single-quoted string. And variables are not expanded in single-quoted strings. You need to change:

```
'dbi:Oracle:host=oracle;sid=$ORACLE_SID;port=1521'
```

to:

```
"dbi:Oracle:host=oracle;sid=$ORACLE_SID;port=1521"
```

Comment: @xaglez: But that's exactly what Dada suggested in his comment above. And you said that didn't work.